# Calculate the discount in a program in C language

Tags: c

I have a plan that gives the total price of the products and if the purchase is more than 200, it should give a 15% discount. But when displaying the final amount, it displays the zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int count;
    printf("plz enter number of product :");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    int price;
    int allprice;
    float discounted_price ;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<count)  
    {
        printf("plz enter price  %d : ",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &price);
        allprice +=price;
        i++;            
    }
    if(allprice>200)
    {
    float discount_amount = (15*allprice)/100;
    float discounted_price = (allprice-discount_amount);    
    } 

    printf("price before discount : %d ",allprice);
    printf("\n");
    printf("price after discount : %d ",discounted_price);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily the solution but please fix: Ignoring return value of scanf(), no init for allprice, integer  division for discount amount.

Comment: `printf("price after discount : %d ",discounted_price);` mismatch between `%d` and `discounted_price` --- the 1st expects an integer, the 2nd is a float

Comment: You should turn on warnings in your compiler. It should give some message about type mismatch for printf format specifier. Providing `float` parameters ffor `%d` causes undefined behaviour

Comment: Prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `discounted_price` twice.

Once where you calculate it inside the `if`.
Once outside, which you output.
Outputting hence ignores the calculated value.

Change

```
float discounted_price = (allprice-discount_amount);
```

to

```
discounted_price = (allprice-discount_amount);
```

And you also need to change the way of printing it, to match the float type
(and thereby avoid undefined behaviour).

```
printf("price after discount : %f ",discounted_price);
```

Finally, the amounts will be more precise if you avoid the integer division:

```
float discount_amount = (15*allprice)/100.0;
```

And for good measure, init the summation variable (though the effect of that is not always seen) :

```
int allprice =0;
```

For readining input by a human (i.e. prone to format errors) it would be wise to check the return value of `scanf()` and use other verification techniques. But that is beyond the scope of an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should initialize `allprice` to zero in order to calculate the total.
The inital value of the variable, if not initialized is undefined.

The expression

```
(15*allprice)/100;
```

may result in zero because it's doing integer divion since all of the operands (15, allprice, 100) are integers. To avoid this, you can just convert one of the operands to a `float`, or just add a .0 after 100.

```
 (15*allprice)/100.0f;
```

This should fix your problem. Let me know if it helps.

The resulting code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
int count;
printf("plz enter number of product :");
scanf("%d", &count);
int price;
int allprice = 0;
float discounted_price ;
int i = 0;
while(i<count)  
{
    printf("plz enter price  %d : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d", &price);
    allprice +=price;
    i++;            
}
if(allprice>200)
{
float discount_amount = (15*allprice)/100.0f;
discounted_price = (allprice-discount_amount);    
} 

printf("price before discount : %d ",allprice);
printf("\n");
printf("price after discount : %f ",discounted_price);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour (and often incorrect output) for using the wrong format specifier when printing.

Comment: Wrong output because of a local variable shadowing the global and resulting in ignored calculation. When you fix these shortcomings please make sure that this answer still provides an additional new insight, compared to the other answer (which happens to be mine....).

Comment: Yes I didn't notice those. I fixed them in the answer.

Comment: You fixed them, but did not explain them.

Comment: They can just read your comment and figure the context.